# How to increase spacing between lines in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have something similar to that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello,<br/>World!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Both lines

```
Hello,
World!
```

are displayed too close to one another. Any way to increase spacing between them (by a portion of a line width (without another `<br/>`))?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a full example of how to make the line spacing within `<td>`s one and a half times the height of the font:

```html
<html><head>
<style>
td {
    line-height: 150%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello,<br/>World!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) to adjust the, well, line height. So in your case `line-height: 2` will double the line height.

Answer (score 4):

```
td {
    line-height:<value>;
}
```